# What is the answer in this one?

Tags: pattern

This is a question from Brainzilla IQ test. It gives C as the correct answer but I cannot figure out why.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

> Reading left to right, top to bottom; each grid has an extra small black square. So the missing grid must have six small black squares.
>
>  Now notice that the small black squares use the same nine positions in sequence, looping back to the when they reach the bottom right.
>  (Numbering the positions 1-9 in natural order, we have:
>  one square in position 1
>  two squares in positions 2,3
>  three squares in positions 4,5,6
>  four squares in positions 7,8,9,1
>  five squares in positions 2,3,4,5,6.)
>  So the six squares should be in positions 7,8,9,1,2,3, which is answer C.

Answer (score 1):

> Same as above, I noticed that the count increased from 1 square to 9 as we went, but I saw it as adding the sides together, like you would on a die. 1 + 8 make a full grid, 2+7, 4+5, so we need to pick the one that adds to 3 to make a full grid, which is C!